# What is the meaning of &NAME->FIELD, when NAME - pointer on structure, created with typedef?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have an structure, defined like that: `typedef struct Name {} * PName;`.
In other file I create function with argument PName, and using it:

```
FILE.write((PCSTR)&RECORD->SIGNATURE.SEQ_OFFSET, sizeof(DWORD));
```

So question is, why there is a '&' operator? RECORD is a pointer on structure, why can't I just write without '&' and what is meaning of '&' there? I hope my question is clear and not very stupid...

Comment: Presumably, the `.write` function *requires* a pointer to the data it writes. Without the `&`, the first argument would be a copy of the *value* of `SEQ_OFFSET`; the `&` gets the address of that data.

Comment: Would it help if I wrote it like this? `(PCSTR)(&(RECORD->SIGNATURE.SEQ_OFFSET))`

Comment: Note that the `&` applies to `RECORD->SIGNATURE.SEQ_OFFSET`, not to `RECORD`.

Comment: `->` and `.` have higher precedence than `&`, so they happen first.  Thus you're following/dereferencing your RECORD pointer to what it points to, getting that object's SIGNATURE member, and then accessing that object's SEQ_OFFSET member and taking its address.

Comment: Great thanks to Adrian Mole and Chris Uzdavinis

Comment: Just remove the `&` and build your code, the compiler will teach you why you need it.

Comment: "compiler will teach you"  looks qiute scaring